# Problem with shar on Ubuntu on text files

Tags: utf-8

I am trying to produce a `shar` file with contents kept in the clear text inside the shar-file. For the most of it things work fine, but today I met a fairly strange problem:

When I do `shar -T test.tex > file.shar` on the one-liner file, encoded in UTF-8:

```
\chapter{Séries}
```

everything works fine, and when executing `sh file.shar` the file is extracted fine and it is the same as before.

Adding a one line to it and turning the file into:

```
\chapter{Séries}
Séries de potências são essenciais no estudo das funções.
```

the same command produces a shar file that contains the text. But when we execute `sh` (or `unshar`, or change it into an executable file and execute it) it fails the MD5 check upon extraction:

```
$ sh file.shar
x - created lock directory _sh06764.
x - extracting test.tex (text)
test.tex: MD5 check failed
x - removed lock directory _sh06764.
```

and it produces a file that is recognized as ISO-8859 text and it has all accents messed up, as in:

```
\chapter{SÃ©ries}
S©ries de potÃªncias sÃ£o essenciais no estudo das funÃ§Ãµes.
```

I know the manual says that you may have problems e-mailing files produced with the `-T` flag, but this goes beyond mailing -- the file itself is corrupted.

Can anyone share a light on what is going on?

Comment: I don't know if this is a bug or not, but I would use the mixed (`-M`) or binary (`-B`) option of `shar` instead of the text (`-T`) option for non-ASCII files.

Comment: as per the man page's description of the `-T` option, *"If you have files with non-ascii bytes or text that some mail handling programs do not like, you may find difficulties."*

Comment: @FedonKadifeli both `-M` and `-B` produce include the files in NON editable format (uuencoded).

Comment: @steeldriver The phrase seems obviously written to mean _...you may find difficulties MAILING the file_. It says right after that _However, if you are using FTP or SSH/SCP, the non-conforming text files should be okay._ I want to edit them with vi or emacs, so there should be no problem.

Comment: Why do you need to edit a `.shar` file? This seems to me like an https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @FedonKadifeli It is a extremely useful tool when you need to examine an occurrence before committing to an edit. You can just open the editor on the (shar) file and then look for each occurrence before doing a replacement...but my point here is not my purpose -- it is a BUG on the shar/unshar procedure -- even if you want to ftp and scp the files.